# Can glueballs, consisting of massles gluons, get a mass without reference to a Higgs field?

Tags: mass, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

Glueballs, the by the standard model predicted combinations of short-lived combinations of massless gluons, have a mass between 1.4 and 5 (MeV). But where is this mass coming from? From interaction with a Higgs field, or entirely from potential energy provided by the strong force between them?

Comment: What's your guess?

Comment: A hint here is $E=mc^2$ ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glueball mass in non-abelian Yang Mills theory](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44686/)

Comment: The mass is roughly 1.5 GeV, not MeV, and yes it all comes from the strong force

Comment: Yes, you´re right. My mistake. But if all the mass comes from the strong force, isn´t that a mechanism to make particles massive, instead of the Higgs mechanism (I know the coupling between the Higgs excitations and the gluon is zero, but nevertheless). If the quarks and leptons are composed particles (made up of zero mass particles), the same mechanism for them could be applied to them. A new hyper color force can do the job (see Haïm Harari´s theory of rishons; yeah here I am again with my preferred theory).